# Where should i create the database for elgg?

Tags: php, wamp, elgg

When I'm installing Elgg, it asks me for the database name, but doesn't find it as it says it may not exist.  Where should I create it? Should I write its name or its root?

Comment: inside phpmyadmin?

Answer (score 1):

You have to create a database.

you can do it via phpmyadmin or mysql console.

```
CREATE DATABASE dbname CHARACTER SET utf8 COLLATE utf8_unicode_ci;
```

then provide the dbname, mysql user and mysql password to Elgg